# ¿Cómo crear una matriz eligiendo los valores más altos para asignar valores de una columna que compensen los de una fila?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matrices, math

Lo que necesito es hacer esta parte de la implementación del método del algoritmo de aproximación de Vogel en Python para el problema de maximización con actualizaciones de matriz de asignación.

[image]

Aquí mi código:

```py
objetivo = "max"
# objetivo = "min"

#datos del problema condensados en una matriz o tabla de datos
#tabla_datos = [[3, 6, 6, 9, 35], [9, 2, 3, 7, 50], [1, 5, 4, 5, 40], [45, 20, 30, 30, 0]]
tabla_datos = [[5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 500], [2, 5, 3, 1, 0, 330], [2, 4, 0, 1, 1, 120], [140, 220, 360, 80, 150, ]]


# Crear tabla de ganancias
tabla_ganancias = [fila[:-1] for fila in tabla_datos[:-1]]

# Obtener el numero de filas y columnas de tabla_ganancias
m = len(tabla_ganancias)
n = len(tabla_ganancias[0])

# Calcular el número de asignaciones, en este caso es 7
# En este caso m + n - 1 = 3 + 5 - 1 = 7 asignaciones
nro_asignaciones = m + n - 1

# Calcular la oferta y la demanda.
oferta = sum(tabla_datos[i][-1] for i in range(m))
demanda = sum(tabla_datos[-1][j] for j in range(n))

print(nro_asignaciones) # en este caso serán 7 asignaciones
print(oferta) #en este caso serie de 950
print(demanda) #en este caso serie de 950

if objetivo == "max":
```

Partiendo de este código proponga el algoritmo de Vogel, es decir, como el problema es “maximizar” la primera asignación se hizo en la casilla de mayor ganancia que es 6, para la segunda asignación o segunda venta hay varias opciones, como todas tienen una ganancia de 5 , elegimos una de ellas , para la tercera venta hay dos cajas con 5 en la misma fila , elegimos una de las 5 , luego como esa fabrica aun tiene toneladas para vender elegimos la ultima caja con ganancia de 5 , para la quinta asignación queda como la caja con mayor ganancia, la de 3, la sexta venta a la caja con ganancia 1, y finalmente la última venta en la casilla que no tiene ganancia.

Ve haciendo las asignaciones, e imprime una por una. **Estas serían las salidas que necesitarías obtener, es decir, imprimir cada vez que hagas un trabajo.**

```py
#construya esta matriz de ceros con las dimensiones m y n
# Inicializar matriz de asignación con ceros
tabla_asignaciones = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)] # m x n 
#en este caso...
tabla_asignaciones = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#In this case   m + n - 1 = 3 + 5 - 1 = 7 assignments

#asignacion nro 1
tabla_asignaciones = [[0, 220, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#asignacion nro 2
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#asignacion nro 3
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#asignacion nro 4
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#asignacion nro 5
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#asignacion nro 6
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 90]]

#asignacion nro 7
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 30, 0, 90]]


#Por fin quedándome así...
tabla_asignaciones = [[140, 220, 0, 80, 60], [0, 0, 330, 0, 0], [0, 0, 30, 0, 90]]
```

¿Cómo hago las tareas? Se que para algo asi debo pasar por la matriz y verificar los valores de las utilidades (como es para maximizar debe ir de mayor a menor), y asi hasta agotar los valores de demanda en los valores de oferta

Comment: si quieres hacer operaciones con matrices deberias usar numpy en vez de listas. en vez de  `tabla_asignaciones  = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)]` es tan facil como hacer `tabla_asignaciones  = np.zeros((m, n))` y muchas otras operaciones que haces se pueden optimizar con numpy. sumar filas o columnas es tan facil como `np.sum(matriz, axis=0)` o `np.sum(matriz, axis=1)`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki No habria ningun problema en usar o no usar numpy, lo que me esta dando problemas es que no encuentro un modo de expresar la logica del algoritmo de Vogel en python. Para esto deberia recorrer la matriz m x n y verificando cuales tienen mayores ganancias establecer las asignaciones sobre la matriz de zeros. Sé que hay muchos modos de plantearlo pero estube provando y no puedo llegar a que funcione

Comment: En mi código (en la pregunta), lo primero que hice fue calcular el número de filas m y el número de columnas n, luego usé la fórmula m + n - 1 para encontrar el número de asignaciones a realizar, y usando el valor aún almacenado en m y en n crean la matriz de ceros donde se colocarán las asignaciones. De este modo tan solo quedan las asignaciones, que es donde radica el problema de esta pregunta.